# ComboBox using ItemsSource binding affects other properties

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, properties

I have a combo box that displays a list of available system colors.  Each item in the combo box has a preview rectangle and the text color name.  At a given time I may need as many as 6 of these combo boxes on the screen at once.  I created a static list of items to reuse across all combo boxes to reduce overhead.  It works, and it is fast, but now when I change other combo box properties such as setting the font weight to bold, it affects all combo boxes, not just the one I applied the property to.

Here is my code, all done in code behind.

Declaration of the list I reuse and the combo box:

```
    static private List<ListViewItem> _colorItems = null;
    ComboBox _comboBoxColorList;
```

Then in the constructor for my control that contains the combo box I have the code for the initial creation of the list:

```
        if (_colorItems == null)
        {
            _colorItems = new List<ListViewItem>();

            PropertyInfo[] colorProperties = typeof(Colors).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
            Dictionary<String, Color> colorDictionary = colorProperties.ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => (Color)p.GetValue(null, null));
            ListViewItem newItem;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<String, Color> keyPair in colorDictionary)
            {
                newItem = CreateListViewItem(keyPair.Key, keyPair.Value);
                _colorItems.Add(newItem);
            }
        }
```

Then I create the combo box:

```
        _comboBoxColorList = new ComboBox();
        _comboBoxColorList.Height = Constants.ListViewPropertyComboBoxHeight;
        _comboBoxColorList.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        _comboBoxColorList.Background = Brushes.White;
        _comboBoxColorList.ItemsSource = _colorItems;
        _comboBoxColorList.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(comboBoxColorList_SelectionChanged);
        Children.Add(_comboBoxColorList);
```

Then later one in an event handler I have this code to set the combo box to bold:

```
            _comboBoxColorList.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
```

If I make it so that _colorItems is not static everythings behaves as it should, but it is slow.  When _colorItems is static it is very fast, but the line above makes all combo boxes taht share the item source bold.

Any insight or wisdom would be great.

Comment: Tags do not belong into the title, leave it...

Comment: please post you code where you create a second combo box.  Please post how you attach the event handler and the entire event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating `ListBoxItems` directly, let this be done by the Framework. In fact you do alot in code which can, and should, be done in XAML.

To make it simple:

Create an `ObservableCollection` with a new class you create, call it maybe `ColorInfo` add all your properties like name, the real color. And fill this list with all your colors.
This can be reused as often as you want.

```
class ColorInfo
{
    public Color Color{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}

ObservableCollection<ColorInfo> myColors;
```

Now, you set this List as the `ItemsSource` of your `ComboBox`. And finally you provide an item template, how each entry should look like.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="_comboBoxColorList">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
            <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="16" Height="16">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Fill="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Of course you could extract the Template and reference it via StaticResource.

Comment: I'm working through updating to try your approach.  The software I have is very dynamic, what is displayed on screen is based on what is read in through a configuration file.  This is why I typically always do everything in code behind, that and the fact that I don't have a solid grasp on WPF yet.  What do you mean by extract the template and reference is via static resource?  I don't have an xaml file accompanying the cs file where I am creating this combo box.  Therefore I don't know where to put the item template you define.  Could I define it in App.xaml and reference it?  If so then how?

Comment: Sure you can do that, in fact thats what i meant :). Just place the Datatemplate in your App.xaml, give it a key like `x:Key="colorComboBoxTemplate"` and then you can use `System.Windows.Application.Current.FindResource("colorComboBoxTemplate")` to look it up in code, don't forget to cast it to DataTemplate. Also you said "very dynamic software" in fact, thats the strong point of WPF. The ObservableCollection could be updated and all controls displaying the contents of it are updated automatically without any additional code.

Comment: Thanks.  So I have it implemented, but it is not fully working.  My list contains all of the color names, but the color preview portion is not showing up.  If I change the fill in the rectangle to be a hard coded color it displays that color, otherwise it leave the rectangle blank.  I changed both the property names, for Color and Name, to something else to make sure that wasn't the problem and it didn't make a difference.  BTW, I did change the TextBlock to use the Text property.

Comment: Another observation, the first time I open a particular combo box now it hesitates, there is a lag, but on subsequent openings it is fast.

Comment: I have confirmed that this does fix the issue when I apply properties such as bold.  So, I just need to get the color to show and also how do you make a programmatic default selection?

Comment: @WPFNewbie i think i made a small mistake regarding the color, i updated my answer try again and see if that helps. The Default Selection can be done using SelectedIndex="0" or nicer with IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem, which would be a bit more to explain :)

Comment: Awesome, that works great.  To select the item I created a method that iterates through the Items collection for the combo box and compares the Name of each ColorInfo item until it finds a match, then it returns the ColorInfo item.  Then I just use _comboBoxColorList.SelectedItem = FindItem(colorName); and it works.  I would prefer more elegant, but it works which is good for now.

Answer (score 0):

If those `ListViewItems` are the ones from the framework you should not do that. If you have a list that is shared between controls it should only contain data, not UI-elements. If you need the data to be displayed in a certain way use the `ItemTemplate` and/or the `ItemContainerStyle`.

See also: [Styling and Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx)

*(Just setting the ItemsSource is not a binding by the way...)*